# How to force rvalue reference to be "restricted" alias?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, strict-aliasing

In the C++ standard (N4618, $17.5.4.9, [res.on.argument], (1.3)) it is said that implementation are free not to perform aliasing check on rvalue reference:

> If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that
>   this parameter is a unique reference to this argument. [
>   Note:
>   If the parameter is a generic parameter
>   of the form
>   T&&
>   and an lvalue of type
>   A
>   is bound, the argument binds to an lvalue reference (14.8.2.1)
>   and thus is not covered by the previous sentence.
>   — end note
>   ] [
>   Note:
>   If a program casts an lvalue to
>   an xvalue while passing that lvalue to a library function (e.g. by calling the function with the argument
>   std::move(x)
>   ), the program is effectively asking that function to treat that lvalue as a temporary.
>   The implementation is free to optimize away aliasing checks which might be needed if the argument
>   was an lvalue.
>   — end note
>   ]

I would like such an assumption to be applied to an entire translation unit. For example, the function `f`:

```
 class A{
    int a;
      //....
 };
 int f(A&& r1,A&& r2){
   r1.a=10;
   r2.a=3;
   return r1.a;
 }
```

Produces the following assembly:

```
    movl    $10, (%rdi)
    movl    $3, (%rsi)
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    retq
```

Where the return value is a load of `r1.a`, because the compiler take into account that `f` might be called this way: `f(move(an_A),move(an_A))`

Now if I declare one of the parameter as restricted:

```
int f(A&& __restrict__ r1,A&& r2){
   r1.a=10;
   r2.a=3;
   return r1.a;
 }
```

We get the following assembly:

```
    movl    $10, (%rdi)
    movl    $3, (%rsi)
    movl    $10, %eax
    retq
```

In this case we say to the compiler to assumes that the parameter `r1` and `r2` are never bounded to the same object. So it returns directly the value stored in `a.a`.

This is exactly the kind of optimization that is allowed by the C++ standard for any library function taking rvalue reference parameters.

I believe that in most (if not all) real case program, a call like `f(move(an_A),move(an_A))` will certainly cause "undocumented behavior" because as a programmer I will never expect a user to pass two rvalue reference arguments both bounded to the same object.

So I have few questions:

1. Is their real case where a call like `f(move(an_A),move(an_A))` happens, so that when implementing `f` the programmer had to take care of this call case?
2. If no, why compiler does not make the assumption that all rvalue reference parameters are "restricted"?
3. Is their any optimization option to force the compiler to assumes that all rvalue reference parameters are "restricted"?

Comment: The rules in §17 are aimed more at the library implementers than the compiler. For example, it is allowed to implement move assignment in the standard library assuming that `x = std::move(x);` doesn't happen.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, I know §17 is intendent to library implementers, this is exactly what is said in the question.

Comment: I have checked your case `x=std::move(x)` that does not cause trouble to defines x as restricted... I'd rather make entensive tests.